# ScrollSpy show wrong active tab when used with JS tabbed content

Tags: javascript, tabbed, scrollspy

I have a project in which I use ScrollSpy and I have a section with tabbed content. The problem is that the script from this tabbed content blocks ScrollSpy showing the correct active item in the nav bar. This tabbed content is in the 3rd section of the page, all goes well until I select 4th menu item and from there on all goes wrong. I think that ScrollSpy is looking for the hidden tabs and somehow counts them too. Is there a way of forcing ScrollSpy to skip searching in one particular section and just move on? Or do you have any other idea on this? Here's the link to the problematic page http://oz.zz.mu/HongKongExpats/ maybe it will help you.

PS. The menu works correctly, it scrolls to the correct section, it only show the wrong menu item as active.

PPS. ScrollSpy it's showing as active the last menu item because I have to have body height: 100%, but I've managed to hide that with a last hidden menu item.

Answer (score 0):

try this: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/quanganh/Tj3ha/6)

if Scrollspy highlight final element, you can add

> height: 100%

to html and body tag